# Prove that if $a|b$ and $b|c$ then $a|b-2c$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that if $a|b$ and $b|c$ then $a|b-2c$.

$b = ak$ for some integer $k$. $(i)$

$c = bl$ for integer $l$. $(ii)$

What I want to know is do I substitute $(ii)$ into $(i)$ next?

Answer (score 3):

Now you take $b-2c = ak - 2bl = ak - 2akl = a(k-2kl)$

Answer (score 2):

if $a|b$ then $b=na$ and $b|c$ then $$c=mb$$ and we get $$b-2c=na-2mb=na-2mna=a(n-2mn)=ak$$ for some integers $m,n,k$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just substiute $c$ in the relation you want to prove
$$b-2c=b-2bl=b(1-2l)=ak(1-2l)$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets set $b=ak$ and $c=bl=akl$.

In that case, we can substitute: $$a|b-2c \implies a|ak-2akl \implies a|ak(1-2l)$$
Since $$l\in \mathbb{Z} \implies 2l\in \mathbb{Z} \implies 1-2l\in \mathbb{Z}$$
Lets set $1-2l = x$: $$a|akx \implies a|b-2c$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a|b$ and $b|c$, then $a|c$.

Thus: $a|b-2c \iff a|b - 2(a|c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is, what should you do next?

To answer this, just look at what you are trying to prove.

You are trying to prove that $$a\;|\;b-2c$$

So, the question is, if you write $b-2c = am$, then is $m$ an integer or not?

So, solve for $m$ and see if you get an expression that is always an integer.

$$m = \frac{b - 2c}{a} = \frac{b - 2bl}{a} = \frac{ak - 2akl}{a} = k-2kl$$

Since $k$ and $l$ are integers, we see that $m$ must be an integer as well.
QED.